# Harbor - Configure Http using Cloudflare

Tags: https, cloudflare, harbor

I'm making some tests with harbor container registry.
In order to publish it to production I wanted to add the ssl support.

As cloudflare provides it I'm wondering if is it possible to make it work.

So far I've created a dns record in cloudflare pointing to my harbor instance, proxied.

I've followed the steps under [documentation](https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/install-config/configure-https/) to configure the https from harbor.

I was able to access the registry with the domain name and the certificates appears to be valid..

But when I tried to push the image to it, it complained about the certificate being invalid

Do you have any clues why?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found out my mistake.

In order to setup the certificate I needed to use the cloud-flare full strict mode.

I'll leave all my steps here, in case someone needs it.

## Cloud flare

### Setup dns registry.

[image]

### SSL/TLS

Go to SSL/TLS => Overview

And change to **Full (strict)**
[image]

#### Origin Server

Now go to SSl/TLS Origin Server and create a new certificate
[image]

Copy the value from **Origin Certificate** to a text file with **.crt** extension
[image]

Copy the value from **Private Key** to a text file with **.key** extension
[image]

Save de cloud flare CA certificate in the same place.[more info](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca)

## Harbor(Linux)

Create two folders:

- `mkdir -p /data/cert`
- `mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d`

Copy the files you have created with names:

- cert.crt =>**domain.com.crt**
- key.key => **domain.com.key**
- ca.crt=> **ca.key**

In the harbor hosts run the following commands

`openssl x509 -inform PEM -in /data/cert/domain.com.crt -out /data/cert/domain.com.cert`

> Convert domain.com.crt to yourdomain.com.cert, for use by Docker.

- `cp /data/cert/domain.com.cert /etc/docker/certs.d/`
- `cp /data/cert/domain.com.key /etc/docker/certs.d/`
- `cp /data/cert/ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/`

> Copy the server certificate, key and CA files into the Docker certificates folder on the Harbor host. You must create the appropriate folders first.

### Edit the harbor.yaml file

In order to make the ssl works you need to uncomment and change the properties in the ssl section

Also it's recommended to change the **hostname**(both on machine and harbor.yaml) with the same you've set up in your dns

If you have already started the harbor:

- stop with the `docke-compose down` command
- run /harbor/prepare script
- run the `docker-compose up -d` command